# C++ statement compiler error

Tags: c++, iterator

i have a statement in my program which does a comparision of elements of a two vectors

```
 if(!*(it2+3).compare(*(lines_in_file.begin())))
```

the compiler error i am getting is:

```
test_file.cpp:140: error: 'class __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::string*, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > >' has no member named 'compare'
```

`it2`'s type is :

```
vector<std::string>::iterator it2=rec_vec.begin();
```

`lines_in_file` type is :

```
vector<std::string> lines_in_file=split(argv[2],',');
```

split function declaration is :

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim)
```

I am confused a bit.already spent a lot of time thinking. 
could any one please help?

Comment: Just break down that humongous expression already. Do the math: it is confusing _YOU_ even more than the compiler, and now it is taking _MY_ time to fix your bugs. OT: i think you are reinventing diff algorithms. Don't. Use a library.

Comment: A good compiler would give an "unreadable code" warning! Are you paying for hitting the spacebar occasionally?

Comment: Don't use `std::string::compare`, use the operator `!=`. Don't use `*(lines_in_file.begin())` use `lines_in_files.front()`. Try to use `const_iterator` if possible (don't know the use case here)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the operator "." have greater precedence that "*" so this should solve the problem.

```
if(!(*(it2+3)).compare(*(lines_in_file.begin())))
```

Comment: To elaborate, operator `.` has higher precedence than operator `*`.  Adding the parentheses gives the intended parse.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because `.` operator [has higher precedence](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/language/operator_precedence) than `*` operator. Use this:

```
if(!(it2+3)->compare(*(lines_in_file.begin())))
```

or this

```
if(!(*(it2+3)).compare(*(lines_in_file.begin())))
```

(which are equal)

Answer (score 1):

Precedence of the member access operator (`.`) is [higher than the precedence](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/language/operator_precedence) of indirection operator (`*`). So your code is interpreted as:

```
if(!*( (it2+3).compare( *(lines_in_file.begin()) ) ))
```

Hence the error. (extra spaces is added for clarity)

So the fix is this:

```
if(! ( *(it2+3) ).compare( *(lines_in_file.begin()) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

THe * operator is applied to the result of

```
(it2+3).compare(*(lines_in_file.begin()))
```

This is not what you want. Just use ():

```
(*(it2+3)).compare(*(lines_in_file.begin()))
```

Comment: Wow. We all responded in the same time, it seems! :]